# What components should I use for building a Java WYSIWYG HTML editor

Tags: java, swing

I like to build java WYSIWYG HTML to practice my or better learn Java swing all the simple swing layouts and simple components i understand , but what should i use to represent tables text place holders html graphic Div representation and so on.. they all have to have drag and drop icons that i drop to the main windows and reside it and move it for this what Java swing component shell i use?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, to draw grids and lines, you need to draw the HTML elements graphically on one or more JPanels.

You do this by overriding the paintComponent() method with your **[Graphics](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html)** and **[Graphics2D](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html)** method calls.

Here's a simple **[example](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/)**:

```
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // Dynamically calculate size information
    Dimension size = getSize();
    // diameter
    int d = Math.min(size.width, size.height); 
    int x = (size.width - d)/2;
    int y = (size.height - d)/2;

    // draw circle (color already set to foreground)
    g.fillOval(x, y, d, d);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawOval(x, y, d, d);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might look into [*metaphase editor*](http://www.metaphaseeditor.com/), "A WYSIWYG HTML Editor Component for use in Java Applications." It's based on Charles Bell's [`HTMLDocumentEditor`](http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=1&thread=1276).